# Query to get items which are in list and not in list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'tbl_Items' with below columns

```
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [ItemNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TotalPieces] [int] NULL
```

and another table 'tbl_ItemPieces' with below columns

```
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [ItemId] [int] NULL,
    [PieceNo] [int] NULL
```

sample values are like below:

tbl_Items

```
Id  ItemNo  TotalPieces
1   1001    5
2   1002    3
3   1003    4
```

tbl_ItemPieces

```
Id  ItemId  PieceNo
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   2       1
4   2       3
5   3       3
6   3       4
```

I have used below query to get count of available pieces and total pieces and available pieces numbers as comma separated string.

```
    select 
        a.ItemNo, COUNT(b.PieceNo) ActualPieces, a.TotalPieces,    

        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST( PieceNo as varchar(50))
        FROM tbl_ItemPieces b 
        WHERE b.itemId = a.Id
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')    

    from tbl_Items a
    inner join tbl_ItemPieces b
    on a.Id = b.itemId
    group by a.ItemNo, a.TotalPieces, a.Id
```

which results below

```
ItemNo  ActualPieces    TotalPieces AvailablePieces
1001    2                  5            1, 2
1002    2                  3            1, 3
1003    2                  4            3, 4
```

I want another column as a comma separated string which contains piece numbers which are not in the table, say if 5 is the total and pieces included are 1,3 then this column value is '2,4,5'

expected result

```
ItemNo  ActualPieces    TotalPieces  AvailablePieces NotAvailablePieces
1001    2               5            1, 2            3,4,5
1002    2               3            1, 3            2
1003    2               4            3, 4            1,2
```

Comment: get from where ? not in where ?

Comment: @Squirrel I edited my question with sample data.

Comment: how about the expected result ?

Comment: expected result added

Comment: where is the information of `piece numbers which are not in the table` ie `3,4,5` comes from ? Are you assuming the `PieceNo` is a continuous number that starts from `1` ?

Comment: yes if the total is 5 and items in table is 2, 3 then missing are 1,4,5. Piece numbers are continuous numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201299/discussion-between-jiju-john-and-squirrel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution below uses a `recursive cte` (`cte_AllPieceNo`) to generate a list of possible `PieceNo` for each Items

From there, just use that and check for `NOT EXISTS()` in `tbl_ItemPieces`

```
; with
cte_AllPieceNo as                 -- Added this
(
    select  Id, TotalPieces, PieceNo = 1
    from    tbl_Items
    union all
    select  Id, TotalPieces, PieceNo = PieceNo + 1
    from    cte_AllPieceNo
    where   PieceNo < TotalPieces
)
SELECT   
    a.ItemNo, 
    COUNT(b.PieceNo) ActualPieces, 
    a.TotalPieces,
    STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + CAST( PieceNo as varchar(50) )
            FROM    tbl_ItemPieces b 
            WHERE   b.ItemId = a.Id
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as AvailablePieces,
    STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + CAST( c.PieceNo as varchar(50) ) -- added this
            FROM    cte_AllPieceNo c
            WHERE   c.Id    = a.Id
            AND     NOT EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT  *
                        FROM    tbl_ItemPieces d
                        WHERE   d.ItemId    = c.Id 
                        AND     d.PieceNo   = c.PieceNo
                    )
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,2, '') as NotAvailablePieces
FROM    tbl_Items a
        INNER JOIN tbl_ItemPieces b on a.Id = b.ItemId
GROUP BY a.ItemNo, 
         a.TotalPieces, 
         a.Id
```

if you have a `tally table`, you can use that to replace the `recursive cte`

Here is the section of the code that uses tally table.

```
cte_AllPieceNo as
(
    select  Id, PieceNo = n
    from    tbl_Items
            cross join tally
    where   n >= 1
    and     n <= TotalPieces
)
```

Answer (score 2):

only way to achieve this using `recursive query`.

first, is to generate those `PieceNo` using `cte`, then `join` the result to your original query excluding the `PieceNo`.

```
with cte as (
        select a.id, (TotalPieces - count(1)) as ct, 1 as ctr, TotalPieces
        from tbl_Items a
        inner join tbl_ItemPieces b on a.Id = b.itemId
        group by a.id, TotalPieces
        union all 
        select id, ct , ctr + 1, TotalPieces from cte where ctr < TotalPieces
    ) select a.ItemNo, COUNT(b.PieceNo) ActualPieces, a.TotalPieces,
        STUFF((select ', ' + CAST( PieceNo as varchar(50))
            from tbl_ItemPieces b 
            where b.itemId = a.Id
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
        STUFF((select ', ' + CAST( ctr as varchar(50))
            from cte b 
            where b.id = a.Id and concat(id, ctr) not in (select concat(itemid, pieceno) from tbl_ItemPieces)
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
        from tbl_Items a
        inner join tbl_ItemPieces b
        on a.Id = b.itemId
        group by a.ItemNo, a.TotalPieces, a.Id
```